# Getting UserNotFoundException on a specific user in Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm using cognitoUser.authenticateUser to authenticate users. This works for all 30 users I have in Cognito except one. (AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser)

Specifically I can authenticate the user by username but not verified email address. This is the only user I cannot authenticate by email address. The call returns UserNotFoundException when passing email address.

The user's settings are exactly the same as the other users and the verified email address is very simple.

[image]

email: foo@bar.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like an untrimmed email was used to create the user. Even though the email in the Cognito console shows no leading spaces, you cannot use that email to log in if it was created with leading spaces.

adminCreateUser does not complain if email has leading spaces.